How to normalize a matrix in C# using Mathnet.Numerics?
How can I normalize a matrix such that each column has a unit standard deviation and a mean of zero with Mathnet.Numerics?
This is a one-line job in python/pandas, but I need to do something in Excel so am trying to use C#.
I pass rawData as a double array and tried the following code but no luck,
Matrix<double> myMatrix = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(rawData);
var normMatrix = myMatrix.NormalizeColumns(1.0);

So the other option is to manually calculate it, but I have not found a function to directly calculate the standard deviation of a column/vector. Is there an equivalent for the .std() function in pandas?
Also the documentation is a bit more terse/less intuitive.
Would appreciate any help.
